# case-of / case expression with or in pattern matching possible?

Tags: haskell

I am learning haskell on my own. And was working on implementing a custom List data type using basic lists and case of.

So data structure is something similar to this

```
data List = List [String] | EmptyList deriving Show
```

now if I am doing case expressions for base case, I have to do two matchings. A simple example would be the size function

```
size :: List -> Int
size lst = case lst of
  (List []) -> 0
  EmptyList -> 0
  (List (x:xs)) -> 1 + size (List xs)
```

Can't I do something like combining the two base cases of list being empty `(List [])` and `EmptyList` somehow to reduce redundancy?

```
size :: List -> Int
size lst = case lst of
  (List []) | EmptyList -> 0
  (List (x:xs)) -> 1 + size (List xs)
```

I have tried searching all over the net for this, but unfortunately wasn't able to find anything concrete over matching multiple patterns in one case.

Comment: I would prefer to use pattern matching that explicit `case` statements - but either way you need separate cases for these 2. The only way I think to use a single statement with an "or" operator is to use guards - which I personally find less readable here than putting each case on a separate line. In any case, the best solution here to reducing redundancy is to use a type which doesn't have this redundancy built in. (ie. it has only one way to represent the empty list)

Comment: Ocaml has "or patterns" similar to the one you mention, but Haskell does not. You need to use two `case` branches. Alternatively, one could exploit view patterns / pattern synonyms to create a single branch, but that would require some preliminary boilerplate, making the code longer.

Comment: you could use _  that cover all other options so do the non empty first and use _ for the rest of your cases

Comment: If you are learning on your own then I would have a look at this one `data List' a = Empty | Node a Int List'`.

Comment: Are there *any* functions which should return different results for `EmptyList` and `List []`? What do they do?

Comment: @DanielWagner nope there are no such functions. That's why I wanted to combine the two cases. I know how to do it using guards or multiple declarations but was wondering if this could be achieved using case expressions or not.

Comment: @dave yep good point, I guess I'll have to go with that. But still, I'm kinda surprised at this limitation.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you should consider why you have separate constructors for `List` and `EmptyList` in the first place. The empty list clearly is already a special case of a list anyway, so this is an awkward redundancy. If anything, you should make it

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty
data List' a = NEList (NonEmpty a) | EmptyList
```

Another option that would work for this specific example is to make the empty case into a “catch-all pattern”:

```
size :: List -> Int
size lst = case lst of
  (List (x:xs)) -> 1 + size (List xs)
  _ -> 0
```

BTW there's no reason to use `case` here, you can also just write two function clauses:

```
size :: List -> Int
size (List (x:xs)) = 1 + size (List xs)
size _ = 0
```

Anyways – this is generally discouraged, because catch-all clauses are an easy place for hard to detect bugs to creep in if you extend your data type in the future.

Also possible, but even worse style is to use a boolean *guard match* – this can easily use lookups in a list of options, like

```
size lst | lst`elem`[EmptyList, List []] = 0
size (List (x:xs)) = 1 + size (List xs)
```

Equality checks should be avoided if possible; they introduce an `Eq` constraint which, quite needlessly, will require the *elements* to be equality-comparable. And often equality check is also more computationally expensive than a pattern match.

Another option if you can't change the data structure itself but *would* like to work with it as if `List []` and `EmptyList` were the same thing would be to write custom *pattern synonyms*. This is a relatively recent feature of Haskell; it kind of *pretends* the data structure is actually different – like `List'` – from how it's really layed out.

Comment: Size was just an example function. But I like your idea of `_`  as I can use it to achieve the same in cases I suppose.
I am aware of how it can be achieved using guards/multiple declarations. What I was wondering whether it was possible to combine cases together or not.

Comment: `elem` introduces an Eq constraint, which is quite a bummer for this function

Comment: @amalloy yes – that's what I meant with “even worse style”, but I should have elaborated.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, you say

> there are no such functions [which should return different results for `EmptyList` and `List []`]

therefore I recommend merging these two constructors in the type itself:

```
data List = List [String] deriving Show
```

Now you no longer need to distinguish between `EmptyList` and `List []` in functions that consume a `List`.

...in point of fact, I would go even further and elide the definition entirely, simply using `[String]` everywhere instead. There is one exception to this: if you need to define an instance for a class that differs in behavior from `[String]`'s existing instance. In that exceptional case, defining a new type is sensible; but I would use `newtype` instead of `data`, for the usual efficiency and semantics reasons.